# Is there any way to find how many rows are deleted for kusto purge command?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

We use purge command to delete some rows for Kusto table. I understand we can query data to get how many rows we want to delete firstly, then use that predicate to run purge command. But just curious is there anyway for us to know how many rows are deleted finally and directly from the operationId of the purge command? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not exposed as part of the command result. If you execute the 2-step purge, then the 1st step returns the expected number of records to purge - this [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-purge#example-two-step-purge). After the command starts, it does not return the number of records that were eventually purged.